# Is a List<T> thread safe if you are only altering values?

Tags: c#, list, thread-safety

If I have a list with 100 items, and 4 threads that alter 25 items each such that they never alter each other's items, will the list be 'thread safe' ie. will it work as expected?

An example would be, you have an array of 1000 cats and their 'name' property is blank as they haven't been named. You want to go through and name them all, but you want it to be multithreaded. So you create 10 threads and tell each one to only do 0-99, 100-199 etc. and set them off.

Comment: Yes.  Do consider that creating and starting the thread already takes more time than changing the elements.  You are not ahead.

Comment: `Parallel.For()` will do the partitioning for you. W/o the cost of separate threads but for toggling 1 property it still won't gain you much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work because you are only reading from the list. You don't write to it.

Comment: Do you mean, I don't write to the list itself, only the objects it references, and never simultaneously?

Comment: ...writing to elements of the list, not modifying the structure of the list itself

Answer (score 2):

As the others have already pointed out, the act of reading is thread-safe by nature. Concurrency only becomes an issue when certain threads want to write and/or others want to read from a resource.

Having said that, I can add that if you use a collection for this purpose, the use of an explicit readonly collection (or simply the use of an IEnumerable) can be considered. [.NET now offers these readonly collections out of the box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx). This makes it more explicit that you're only reading from the collection.

And on a side-note: I don't know the context of your requirements, and perhaps you just oversimplified the problem here, but serial access to in-memory collections is blazingly fast, so you having multiple threads read from the collection is only well founded in the following cases:

- You're not reading from memory but from disk (I/O is slow)
- The action you're performing to manipulate the objects is slow (like in the order of milliseconds or greater, instead of simple property modification)

Comment: Reading need not be thread safe unless it is documented as being so. Consider a mru cached dictionary for example.

Comment: Eric, it depends on how you define 'reading'. In the case of an MRU-cache, a read also implies an internal write to register that that item has been read just now, causing a (hidden) side effect. That's what makes it not thread-safe by default. Having said that, I agree that you cannot blindly trust any instance is thread-safe when calling what seems to be a 'read-method', so in any programming context, make sure the documentation tells you it's thread-safe or you are damn sure it is (like with the List<T>). :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are not midifying the list itself(adding or deleting items) and you can guaratee that 4 threads only work with their own objects you will be fine from the thread sync point of view

Answer (score 0):

You can use the parallel linq features instead of some homebrewn threading:

```
namespace CSharp
{
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;

  class Cat
  {
    public string Name { get; set; }
  }

  class Program
  {
    private static void Main()
    {
      var cats = new List<Cat>();

      for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
      {
        cats.Add(new Cat());
      }

      cats.AsParallel().ForAll(cat => cat.Name = "Carlo");

      foreach (var cat in cats)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(cat.Name);
      }

      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```